# ¿Cómo puedo crear un renderizado condicional complejo en ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo la siguiente aplicación pero quisiera crear un condicional que creo es un poco complejo y es el siguiente

Si la consulta tiene más de 10 coincidencias que me salga el siguiente mensaje debajo del input

*Too many matches, specify another filter*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Si la consulta tiene menos de 10 coincidencias muestre los nombres de los paises que coincidan*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Y si inicia la aplicacion sin ninguna letra en el filtro de busqueda que muestre todos los paises*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código, puesto que es en react ocupo CodeSandbox.

Aplicación de Filtro de Países:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [findCountries, setFindCountries] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then((response) => {
      // console.log(response);
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleFindCountry = (event) => {
    setFindCountries(event.target.value);
  };

  const findCountry = countries.filter((country) =>
    country.name.toLowerCase().includes(findCountries.toLowerCase())
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        find countries <input onChange={handleFindCountry} />
      </p>

      <ul>
        {findCountry.map((country) => (
          <li key={country.alpha2Code}>{country.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit new]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente deberías validar que el resultado de la búsqueda sea mayor a 10 y que el input de búsqueda este con algún valor.

```
{(findCountry.length > 10 && (findCountries && findCountries !== '')) ? `Too many matches, specify another filter` : findCountry.map(country =>
        <li key={country.alpha2Code}>{country.name}</li>)}
```

Nos comentas si es lo que necesitas :D

Comment: Muchas gracias compa, debido a la facilidad de la implementación de código con respecto al problema planteado, funciona correctamente la solución que propones. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

En realidad no es demasiado complejo, pero sí requeriría varios cambios en tu código.

Podrían haber varias formas de hacerlo, pero yo te propongo esta:

Primero creamos un nuevo estado llamado `limitExceded` y lo inicializamos en `false`.

```
const [limitExceded, setLimitExceded] = useState(false);
```

Con ese estado definiremos qué es lo que se mostrará en la pantalla de esta forma...

```
<ul>
    {!limitExceded &&
      findCountry.map((country) => (
        <li key={country.alpha2Code}>{country.name}</li>
      ))}
  </ul>
  {limitExceded && <p>{limitExceded}</p>}
```

Así, si `limitExceded` es `false` imprimirá todos los países pero sí ese estado tiene contenido entonces mostrará el mensaje que le pondremos más adelante.

A continuación, creamos una nueva función `findCountry2` que en vez de procesar los datos del estado `findCountries`, trabajará con un argumento que le vamos a pasar. Eso lo vamos a hacer en la función `handleFindCountry` .

Dentro de dicha función, como argumento le pasamos lo que escribimos en el `input` y creamos un nuevo objeto llamado `conutriesFound`.

```
 let conutriesFound = findCountry2(event.target.value);
```

Y ahora sí podemos establecer el limite de resultados que se mostrarán.

```
if (conutriesFound.length === 0 || conutriesFound.length < 10 || event.target.value === "") {
  setFindCountries(event.target.value );
  setLimitExceded(false);
} else {
  setLimitExceded("Too many matches, specify another filter");
}
```

Si los países encontrados son menos de 10 o 0, o el input está vacío, volvemos `false` a  `limitExceded` y actualizamos el estado `findCountries`. Caso contrarío, al estado `limitExceded` le pasamos el mensaje "Too many matches, specify another filter".

Haciendo todos esos cambios, todo el código quedaría así:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [findCountries, setFindCountries] = useState("");
  const [limitExceded, setLimitExceded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then((response) => {
      // console.log(response);
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleFindCountry = (event) => {
    let conutriesFound = findCountry2(event.target.value);
    if (
      conutriesFound.length === 0 ||
      conutriesFound.length < 10 ||
      event.target.value === ""
    ) {
      setFindCountries(event.target.value);
      setLimitExceded(false);
    } else {
      setLimitExceded("Too many matches, specify another filter");
    }
  };

  const findCountry = countries.filter((country) =>
    country.name.toLowerCase().includes(findCountries.toLowerCase())
  );
  const findCountry2 = (countriesToSearch) =>
    countries.filter((country) =>
      country.name.toLowerCase().includes(countriesToSearch.toLowerCase())
    );

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        find countries <input onChange={handleFindCountry} />
      </p>

      <ul>
        {!limitExceded &&
          findCountry.map((country) => (
            <li key={country.alpha2Code}>{country.name}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
      {limitExceded && <p>{limitExceded}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit new]

Pruébalo en el **fork** que hice de tu código.

Aclaro que, como dije al principio, hay otras maneras de hacer esto y de hecho esta forma que te ofrezco quizás no sea la más limpia. Pero al menos aportaría una solución a lo que buscas hacer.

Comment: Muchas gracias compa, tu solución realmente hace lo que requería. Saludos.